# Convert blinking (On/Off) power LED to fading

Tags: led, power

I couldn't come up with a better title...but here's the explanation.

Basically, I need to create a small circuit for my PC to attach to the power LED. The way my motherboard works is that if the system is powered-on then the LED is ON. But when the system goes to standby the LED starts blinking.

I want to do two things:

1. Have two separate color LEDs for each state i.e. powered-on(green) vs standby (amber).
2. I want the standby LED to slowly fade-in/out (not fully out though, half-way).

I figured that I can make the blinking signal fade by attaching a capacitor and a diode (to prevent current going back to the motherboard). That should take care of standby light.

However, I can't figure out how to switch LEDs when the current goes from continous to intermittent. So when the system goes to standby the LED switches from green to amber. Any ideas? Btw, I don't want a expensive or complex circuit. I need something that will Not require any outside power-source and will work just from the current coming for the power-LED. Someone suggested me to use two RC circuits as such:

Explanation here: http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showpost.php?p=411691&postcount=8

Comment: It's really hard, because different colors require also different voltage...the red will be stronger than the green, even if it will fade after...

Comment: I've heard that fade-blinking effect called "breathing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to detect the blinking/not blinking.

An RC lowpass filter followed by a comparator would do this.

Then you need to use the comparator output to switch between the LEDs.

I have thrown together a quick circuit that should work (sorry for the mess but I'm rushing at the moment):

[image: PC LED power]

And the simulation:

[image: PC LED power sim]

The pink line is the PC power indicator in, you can see it starts to toggle after around 2ms (I forgot to expand the time realistically, sorry - depending on the frequency of the flashing you will need to adjust R1 and C1 - probably 10k and 100uF are better values)

When it starts to toggle the voltage after the RC filter (RC_FILT) drops below V_REF and the comparator output switches (not shown)
Depending on the state of the output (5V or 0V) either the NPN or PNP transistor is on, and the LED in series with it is lit.
The botton graph is of the current through each LED - you can see one drops to 0 and the other turns on when the toggle starts/stops.

Hope this helps - ask if you don't understand anything and I will try to add some more later if needed.

EDIT - here is another version that does not use a separate power supply. It's a quick hack so I make no guarantees - the components shown are guidelines, you can use any small signal schottky and pretty much any small N-channel MOSFETs. This is about as simple as I think you can make something to do what you want:

[image: PC LED Power 2]

Here's the sim:

[image: PC LED Power sim 2]

Comment: What about using a bigger limiting resistor for the red LED, that has a lower drop?

Comment: @clabacchio - yes good point, the values for the resistors would need to be adjusted too - I just put two of the same random LEDs in there from those available in LTSPICE. The circuit is more a rough concept, the components shown (e.g. 2N2222) are not recommendations (could use FETs fro example)

Comment: Also re-reading the question I realise this doesn't cover all requirements, such as the standby not turning fullyoff (didn't notice that first time - could easily add a voltage divider to cover that though) Also the no other power requirement - this would be a bit more difficult as we would be wanting to power 2 LEDs instead of one, it would depend on what is available on the original LED output and the circuit would need to be adjusted. It would be easier just to "borrow" 5V from the PC supply.

Comment: @OliGlaser thanks for the detailed response. Actually both don't have to be powered on at the same time. Green should turn on when signal is continous and amber, when the signal is intermittent. Did you look at the link I referenced? Can you confirm if that guy's logic makes any sense?

Comment: @tunafish24 - Yes, I looked at the whole thread also. The post you link to sort of makes sense for just the amber fade in/out, but both LEDs would blink on startup. I can't look at the attached circuit as I'm not a member, maybe his circuit is different from what I imagine (can you copy/link to it?) My circuit uses the RC filter and a comparator to test for the blinking/not blinking and switches LEDs on/off accordingly. The thread mentioned some variations on this theme IIRC.

Comment: blinking at startup is fine..as long as it follows the desired behavior afterwards. The reason I don't want the circuit to use any other power-source is because I don't want to mess arond with my motherboard - I just got a new one. 

Here's that circuit diagram: !(http://s13.postimage.org/6nu10rbqv/indication_light_status.jpg)

Comment: Hmmm, no transistor there although it was mentioned in the post :-) This circuit will blink both LEDs when on standby, and just have one lit when PC is on (the left hand one) By the way, you don't have to take power from the motherboard, you can just take 5V from a spare ATX power socket (e.g a DVD/Hard drive power socket, not the large motherboard one)

Comment: what if we add a slightly larger capacitor in series with the green LED...so during blinking it won't have enough time to charge and green won't come on...or may come on so dim that it will be overrun by amber LED?

Comment: @OliGlaser Can you let me know? I need to take care of this asap. Also, what values for capacitor and resistors do I need for this?

Comment: @tunafish24 - With green and amber and 5V supply, something like 200 ohms for each resistor would be reasonable. For the capacitors, try something like 1uF or above for the series capacitor. With that circuit the green will blink when in standby, there isn't much of a way round that without making a few changes.

Comment: @OliGlaser So whats the fix for blinking green? I really need to get this resolved.

Comment: @tunafish24 - See edit - I have added a second simplified circuit that should get near to what you are asking for. See the notes on components and ask if you don't understand anything.

Comment: @OliGlaser That looks awesome! bit bigger than I expected though. Is there a chance that this circuit might overload the LED pin on my motherboard? should I get 5V caps?

Comment: @tunafish24 - If the LED pin is current limited, then the worst that will happen is that the voltage may sag a bit, it shouldn't damage anything. If you want to though, you can compensate for this by sizing R5 and R6 as necessary (these probably need adjusting anyway - if you are not sure there are answers on here that deal with selecting the series resistor for an LED - I'd start with 300 ohms as a guideline figure for ~10mA each) to take less current (e.g. if the original LED took 20mA, then set each LED to 10mA) I would use caps rated for twice the voltage, so for 5V pick >10V rated.